# C# Sort by boolean equality to static string, followed by sort on integer number ascending

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

I have a `List<Data> myList` where

```
public class Data
{
    public string Classifier;
    public int Code;
}
```

and I want to sort it

1. By whether or not a data's `Classifier` is equal to some static string, we'll just call it `@"Alpha"` for now (non-equals first, equals second)
2. By `Code`, ascending.

So the input data

```
    {
      "Beta", 6
      "Alpha", 4
      "Lambda", 2
      "Beta", 1
      "Alpha", 5
    }
```

would result in

```
    {
      "Beta", 1
      "Lambda", 2
      "Beta", 6
      "Alpha", 4
      "Alpha", 5
    }
```

Specifically, I want the alpha's to settle to the bottom of the list in ascending numerical order.

I'm not sure how to implement a `.Sort Comparison<Data>` instance to support this, and `.OrderBy` doesn't seem to fit the problem.  Any thoughts?

Comment: OrderBy-ThenBy is a good solution. However, note that `Sort` sorts in-place and `OrderBy-ThenBy` produces a sorted sequence without changing the original list. If you *need* to change the original list then you'll have to implement a comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I think `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` combo would work here:

`var result = myList.OrderBy(d => d.Classifier == "Alpha").ThenBy(d => d.Code);`

Answer (score 4):

My preferred solution is Ian Ray's solution of using `OrderBy-ThenBy` to sort a list out-of-place.

What if you needed to sort it in-place?

Build the solution out of smaller parts, each of which is clearly correct.

```
Comparison<int> intComparison = 
  (x, y) => x == y ? 0 : (x < y ? -1 : 1);

Comparison<bool> boolComparison =
  intComparison(x ? 1 : 0, y ? 1 : 0);

Comparison<string> alphaComparison = 
  (x, y) => boolComparison(x == "Alpha", y == "Alpha");

Comparison<Data> dataComparison =
  (x, y) => {
    int a = alphaComparison(x.Classifier, y.Classifier);
    return (a != 0) ? a : intComparison(x.Code, y.Code);
  };
```

Now you have an implementation of `Comparison<Data>` you can pass to `Sort`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the expected output, is not really sorted by the word, You could implement a `bubble sort` comparing the world position but insted of switching the word position, switch the whole registry.

Then the same process for the numbers, limiting the word

```
lambda, 2
beta, 1
beta, 6
alfa, 4
alfa, 5
```

Note grouping by word, or you could just do a bubble sort for the numbers and switch position to the whole registry.